# Can't download file in Android phone - Android..?

Tags: android, permissions, download

I having problem with file download,

I am able to download file in emulator but It is not working with the phone.
I have defined the **permission for the Internet and write SD card**.

I having one doc file on server, and if user click on download. It downloads the file. This **works fine in  emulator** but not working in phone.

**Edit**
My code for download file

```
public void downloadFile(String _url, String fileName) {
        File PATH = Environment
                .getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS);
        try {
            PATH.mkdirs();
            URL url = new URL(_url); // you can write here any link
            File file = new File(PATH, fileName);

            long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
            Log.d("Manager", "download begining");
            Log.d("DownloadManager", "download url:" + url);
            Log.d("DownloadManager", "downloaded file name:" + fileName);
            /* Open a connection to that URL. */
            URLConnection ucon = url.openConnection();

            /*
             * Define InputStreams to read from the URLConnection.
             */
            InputStream is = ucon.getInputStream();
            BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(is);

            /*
             * Read bytes to the Buffer until there is nothing more to read(-1).
             */
            ByteArrayBuffer baf = new ByteArrayBuffer(50);
            int current = 0;
            while ((current = bis.read()) != -1) {
                baf.append((byte) current);
            }

            /* Convert the Bytes read to a String. */
            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
            fos.write(baf.toByteArray());
            fos.close();
            Log.d("ImageManager",
                    "download ready in"
                            + ((System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime) / 1000)
                            + " sec");

        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.d("ImageManager", "Error: " + e);
        }
    }
```

Comment: any errors in the logcat? maybe some code snippets?

Comment: Paste some code, with this information is difficult to help you :)

Comment: Nop,logcat doesn't give any errors.

Comment: i have added code plz refer it,

Comment: If it works on simulator and not on device, then there's probably something wrong with the path(url) you provide or your memory card

Comment: path is  Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try the snippets given bellow...

```
File PATH = Environment
                .getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS);
        try {
            //set the download URL, a url that points to a file on the internet
            //this is the file to be downloaded
            _url = _url.replace(" ", "%20");
            URL url = new URL(_url);

            //create the new connection
            HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

            //set up some things on the connection
            urlConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
            urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);


            //and connect!
            urlConnection.connect();

            //create a new file, specifying the path, and the filename
            //which we want to save the file as.
            File file = new File(PATH,fileName);

            //this will be used to write the downloaded data into the file we created
            FileOutputStream fileOutput = new FileOutputStream(file);

            //this will be used in reading the data from the internet
            InputStream inputStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();

            //this is the total size of the file
            int totalSize = urlConnection.getContentLength();
            Log.i("Download", totalSize+"");
            //variable to store total downloaded bytes
//          int downloadedSize = 0;

            //create a buffer...
            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
            int bufferLength = 0; //used to store a temporary size of the buffer

            //now, read through the input buffer and write the contents to the file
            while ( (bufferLength = inputStream.read(buffer)) > 0 ) {
                    //add the data in the buffer to the file in the file output stream (the file on the sd card
                    fileOutput.write(buffer, 0, bufferLength);
            }
            //close the output stream when done
            fileOutput.close();
            return true;

    //catch some possible errors...
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

make sure you have enters the correct download path(url)